# Inserting a new section to uitable view

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I have table with multiple sections and at particular section I have a button in footer of that section. In that action it should write the code to add the new section below to it . but its not adding any new section below to it.

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]
              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: How do you provide data to your tableview?

Answer (score 1):

On the click of that button, you will have to realod your table and then in the method `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` you will have to return the `numberOfExistingSections + 1`

Let me explain in detail.

First you store your initial number of sections in a variable in your class like:

```
numberOfExistingSections = 5;
```

Then when you click on a button, the method will look like this:

```
- (void) buttonClick {

   // your code

   numberOfExistingSections += 1;
   [yourTable reloadData];
}
```

And your `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` will look like this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return numberOfExistingSections;
}
```

According to the number of sections and rows you are adding, also dont forget to add modify data inside the arrays or dictionaries you are using to fill data in your `UITableView`.

Comment: my code is crashing and getting the following error:    * Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1912.3/UITableView.m:1030
2012-07-05 12:30:48.409 Test[1102:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (2) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (2), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (1 inserted, 0 deleted)

Comment: Did you try my code? I doubt, you are adding rows to the new section or not!!

Comment: @rakesh : Can you write here Kanav's code that you have implemented..may be you are implementing it wrong... +1 to it.

Comment: - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
   
     
        return numberOfExistingSections;
        
}

Comment: - (void) buttonClick {

   [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    
    [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:2] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
 
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    
    numberOfExistingSections += 1;
    
    
    
    [self.tableView reloadData];

   
}

Answer (score 0):

Kanan Vora is incorrect. Your problem is that you need to update your model to add the new section before you update the table view.

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
<- insert new section at index 'n' ->
[self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:n]
              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```